# what HTML status codes go into jquery.ajax done and fail methods

Tags: jquery

Jquery provides methods for handling server response like `done` and `fail`. I'm wondering which status codes returned by the server are handled by callback passed to `done` and which are handled by callback passed to `fail` methods? Apperantly, the status code `200` is handled by `done` callback, and status code `500` is handled by `fail` callback. What about the others?

Answer (score 3):

From the jQuery [source code](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.ajax):

```
isSuccess = status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304;
```

So 2xx or 304 code is successful, anything else is failure.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
if ( status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304 ) {
   //success
}else{
   //failed
}
```

You can even handle the response based on status.

```
request = $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: url,
data: data,
complete: function(e, xhr, settings){
   if(e.status === 200){

   }else if(e.status === 304){

   }else{

   }
   )};
  )};
```

Comment: `)};` typo at the end.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'm using the method `statusCode: {200 : onStatusCode200}` passed to `$.ajax`.